# Replacing portion of marble floor that blocks appliance removal?

Tags: flooring

A couple years ago had an incident where the dishwasher needed to be replaced.  The previous owner had replaced the tiled floor with 3/4" marble slabs, which prevented the removal of the old dishwasher.  I had to use an angle grinder to cut out a section to get the dishwasher out.

I am getting ready to sell the house, and was advised that I need to fix this gap.  However I do not know what type of marble it is, and honestly I feel a lightweight removable filler piece would be a more desirable direction to go, in that it would prevent the next homeowner from having to cut out a portion of the floor to replace the dishwasher in the future.  I have tried looking for "flooring spacers" but that only gave me results regarding laying tile.

I have added a picture since a picture is worth a thousand words.

Any idea what the best way to handle this would be?  The marble itself is white with gray/red/brown mottles and streaks in it.

[image: Flooring with ground-out section]

Comment: I have a similar situation with a later-added wood floor. The height difference in my kitchen, however, is small enough so the dishwasher can be pulled out over the edge of the wood if the front feet of the dishwasher — which screw in and out for height adjustment — are screwed in so the feet are shorter. Screwed in, the dishwasher feet can just clear the finished floor. The dishwasher can then be pulled into the room, with the dishwasher top just clearing the cabinet opening. This wouldn't address the unfinished look, but may allow removal of the appliance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm yes, cabinets need to sit on top of the finish floor- with either flooring under them or shimmed up in another way so they will be at the height that would sit on top of the finish floor. Otherwise you cannot get the DW in. Not doing that is a mistake you would only make once...

In your case you can find a "close enough" piece of marble to replace the hole you made. This would kind of screw the next guy who has to replace the DW. Another option would be to fit a piece of nice wood (maybe matching your cabinets ?) and fasten that down to fill the hole so it can be removed by someone later.

Honestly neither is a very desirable option- truth is it was done incorrectly when they installed the flooring and there is not really a "good" fix for this.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too.  I just don't want to be "that" guy that just passes the problem on down the line.  But I'm already quite a bit more sunk into fixing the house up to sell it than I originally intended on being, so I was hoping there was a better solution than I was coming up with.